# How to allow anonymous access on @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How can I define a `@RequestMapping` method to explicit allow anonymous (unauthorized) access?

The following does not work, always getting  `401 Unauthorized`:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Secured(value={"ROLE_ANONYMOUS"})
public String test() {
    return "OK";
}
```

In general the whole application is secured as follows, using `spring-boot`:

`security.basic.enabled=true`.

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work, with `@Secured("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")`, maybe you have already overriden the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` so this `@Secured("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")` is not taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` method and define your rules there:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/test")
           .permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().regexMatcher("^((?!test).)*$").permitAll();
    }
}
```

I am not sure about a slash before `test` but just try this negative look-around method.